# recursive method to draw a dendrogram

Tags: java, recursion, dendrogram

I have to draw a dendrogram like this :

[image: dendogram]

but much bigger. Which is there as an option for the representation of some data clustering.
So i am stuck with the recursive method to actually draw the dendrogram.

I do get the principle that the draw method should be like

```
 draw(cluster){
      if(clusters.hasChildren()){
         draw(cluster.child1)
         draw(cluster.child2)
      }
      //draw actual cluster here
    }
```

but i am quite stuck at implementing it.

My method at the moment looks like this

```
drawCluster(cluster, startX, startY){
   if(cluster.hasChildren()){
      drawCluster, cluster.child1(), cluster.child1().getDepth * 30, height - cluster.child2.getWidth * 20)
      drawCluster, cluster.child2(), cluster.child2().getDepth * 30, height - 20)
   }
   if cluster.getDepth() == 0 )
      drawLine(500 - 30), height, 500)
   else
      drawLine(500 - (width * 30), height, 500);
}
```

So the space i have for drawing it is 500 px in width and the height total_number_of_Leafs * 20
For now i only draw a line for each cluster just to get the distances correct.
Every time i start the line @  500px minus the depth of the cluster times 20.And draw the line up to 500th pixel.

Also the height is supposed to be the maxHeight. for example when it come to draw lets say the cluster with (1,2) the height in the argument would be 40. And so on.

But this is not working that well. I am basically stuck on how to change the values every time i call the draw method. Also do i need to pass more variable other than the x start of the line and the y?

Any help would be appreciated since i have a deadline to catch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some minimal reproducable example, including data structure and test data?

Comment: The data and the actualy clustering works as intended. Tested with print statements etc. Same goes with the methods to get a cluster width, depth etc. My only problem is the actual representation. If you could give me some tips on how to call the recursive method to draw this exact thing on the image it will be enough to make my method work i think.

Comment: Did not say that those parts are wrong, it just would be a whole lot easier for us to help you if we knew the data structure you are using and had some example to test against.

Comment: Well since its a university assignment i don't want to put the data structure and the actual input data because im not sure if im supposed to ask such a question here or not. I don't think there is anything wrong tbh, its not like i am asking for the asnwer or something. But w/e. Anyway if you could produce something only for this small tree that would be fine. Keep the leafs as they are and have the nodes hold the sum of their underlying clusters. or something similar. Would that be enough? Im sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Painting a dendrogram exactly like that recursively is actually a bit tricky.

The leaf nodes to not "know" their y-position. Additionally, no node does "directly" know where it has to be painted, and how the *lines* should be painted that connect it to its children: All this information is not available before all the leaves (or the children of each node, respectively) have been painted.

I think that an iterative solution could be easier and more flexible. However, here is an implementation using the recursive approach. Note that is a very simple implementation, which (for example) assumes that the data structure for the dendrogram is a *binary* tree, but this should be in line with the example that you posted.

[image: Dendrogram]

BTW: It fills the available space, and I'd **strongly** recommend to avoid "magic constants" and assumptions about the pixel size of the nodes or the painting area as in `drawLine(500 - (width * 30), height, 500)`. Even if you do not want to compute these from the size of the tree and the number of leaf nodes, you should **at least** introduce variables for that so that you can change it more easily later.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class DendrogramPaintTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DendrogramPaintPanel panel = new DendrogramPaintPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);

        f.setSize(1000,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Node<T> 
{
    private final T contents;
    private final List<Node<T>> children;

    Node(T contents)
    {
        this.contents = contents;
        this.children = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    Node(Node<T> child0, Node<T> child1)
    {
        this.contents = null;

        List<Node<T>> list = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        list.add(child0);
        list.add(child1);
        this.children = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public T getContents()
    {
        return contents;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getChildren()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }
}


class DendrogramPaintPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static <T> Node<T> create(T contents)
    {
        return new Node<T>(contents);
    }
    private static <T> Node<T> create(Node<T> child0, Node<T> child1)
    {
        return new Node<T>(child0, child1);
    }


    private Node<String> root;
    private int leaves;
    private int levels;
    private int heightPerLeaf;
    private int widthPerLevel;
    private int currentY;
    private final int margin = 25;

    DendrogramPaintPanel()
    {
        root =
            create(
                create(
                    create("10"),
                    create(
                        create("9"),
                        create(
                            create("8"), 
                            create("7")
                        )
                    )
                ),
                create(
                    create(
                        create("6"),
                        create("5")
                    ),
                    create(
                        create("4"),
                        create(
                            create("3"),
                            create(
                                create("2"),
                                create("1")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    private static <T> int countLeaves(Node<T> node)
    {
        List<Node<T>> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children.size() == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        Node<T> child0 = children.get(0);
        Node<T> child1 = children.get(1);
        return countLeaves(child0) + countLeaves(child1);
    }

    private static <T> int countLevels(Node<T> node)
    {
        List<Node<T>> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children.size() == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        Node<T> child0 = children.get(0);
        Node<T> child1 = children.get(1);
        return 1+Math.max(countLevels(child0), countLevels(child1));
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        leaves = countLeaves(root);
        levels = countLevels(root);
        heightPerLeaf = (getHeight() - margin - margin) / leaves;
        widthPerLevel = (getWidth() - margin - margin)/ levels;
        currentY = 0;

        g.translate(margin, margin);
        draw(g, root, 0);
    }


    private <T> Point draw(Graphics g, Node<T> node, int y)
    {
        List<Node<T>> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children.size() == 0)
        {
            int x = getWidth() - widthPerLevel - 2 * margin;
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(node.getContents()), x+8, currentY+8);
            int resultX = x;
            int resultY = currentY;
            currentY += heightPerLeaf;
            return new Point(resultX, resultY);
        }
        if (children.size() >= 2)
        {
            Node<T> child0 = children.get(0);
            Node<T> child1 = children.get(1);
            Point p0 = draw(g, child0, y);
            Point p1 = draw(g, child1, y+heightPerLeaf);

            g.fillRect(p0.x-2, p0.y-2, 4, 4);
            g.fillRect(p1.x-2, p1.y-2, 4, 4);
            int dx = widthPerLevel;
            int vx = Math.min(p0.x-dx, p1.x-dx);
            g.drawLine(vx, p0.y, p0.x, p0.y);
            g.drawLine(vx, p1.y, p1.x, p1.y);
            g.drawLine(vx, p0.y, vx, p1.y);
            Point p = new Point(vx, p0.y+(p1.y - p0.y)/2);
            return p;
        }
        // Should never happen
        return new Point();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. There is a bug with the margins though - it should read: "int x = getWidth() - widthPerLevel - 2*margin;" (where margin then needs to be globalised).

Comment: @lemon This was an example that I quickly assembled to show the basic idea of the recursive drawing in general. There are certainly several possible improvements (also depending on the application case). But including the margin in the x-computation indeed makes it more agnostic against resizing of the panel, so I edited it accordingly - thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not provide any specific data structure, I can only give pseudo-code. The most important part seems to be to build the tree bottom-up, taking the calculated width of the lower levels into account when constructing the higher levels.

```
func drawCluster(node:Node, depth:int, top:int) -> int:
    if node has children:
        next_top = top
        for child in node.children:
            drawLine(depth, top, depth + 1, next_top)
            next_top = drawCluster(child, depth + 1, next_top)
        return next_top
    else:
        drawLabel(node.label, depth, top)
        return top + text_height
```

Obviously, I could not test this, but I did something similar for a graph layouting algorithms once, so I think this should work, unless I misunderstood you question.

Comment: Well the way i was trying to do it was by having a for loop first going through all the clusters. Since some clusters may actually be Leafs throughout the entire clustering and in that case i want a line that covers the entire width. Then if a cluster has children i call the recursive method to draw that cluster. I am tryign to figure out how does your method can be combined with what i am doing or if i need change it completely.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. So the clusters should be aligned to the right, I guess... Well, in this case you can do similar, except that you'd have to return the depth of the cluster as well, instead of passing it as a parameter. (Returning tuples in Java is a bit ugly, but doable). If that's not what you want, post an example. You don't have to put all your assignment code in the question, just find some sort of abstraction that still carries the essence of the problem. Without that it's really hard to help.